# CaskでGithub上に単純に.elファイルが置いてあるものをパッケージとして扱えますか？

Tags: emacs

Emacsのパッケージ周りの新しく`Cask`に入れ替えているのですが、`Cask`を使ってパッケージではなく単純に`Github`などに置かれている`*.el`ファイルをパッケージのように既にローカルに存在すれば何もせず、ファイルがなければダウンロードしてきて適切な場所に置くといったことはできますか？

Emacs 25.2 で以下の`ndmacro`を入れようとしています。
https://github.com/snj14/ndmacro.el

今までは`~/.emacs.d/git`というディレクトリを作りその下に`git clone`で落としてきたファイルを適時必要なものだけ起動時に読み込むようにしていたのですが、できるならパッケージとして管理したく質問いたしました。

Comment: `(depends-on "ndmacro" :git "https://github.com/snj14/ndmacro.el")` とすれば良いはずなのですが、`ndmacro.el` の先頭行が `;; ndmacro.el` になっていますので、エラーとなってインストールできません。cask のソースコード(`package-legacy.el`) をご覧になればお分かりかと思いますが、`(re-search-forward "^;;; \\([^ ]*\\)\\.el --- \\(.*\\)$" nil t)` となっていますので、`;;; ndmacro.el --- ` に書き換えればインストールできるかと思います。

Comment: `package-legacy.el` をさらに眺めてみたのですが、ファイルの最終行に `;;; ndmacro.el ends here` が必要で、ヘッダ部分(コメント部分)に `Version:` か `Package-Version:` タグが必要らしいです。`xs-mode` は Cask でインストールできますので、https://github.com/emacsmirror/xs-mode/blob/master/xs-mode.el が参考になるかと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。`fork`して試してみたところ無事インストールできました。作者の方にプルリクを送っておきます。あと参考になる公式のドキュメントが見つかりましたのでURLを貼っておきます。 https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Library-Headers.html